# postgres (pgAdmin) database connection issue

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I'm a new sql user (3 days) and I'm having some problems querying data from database tables I've created, whereas there is no problems querying the default 'postgres' database tables. My first thought was that it was a access/privilege problem, but had no effect. I did also notice that my database activity in the dashboard is always idle, whereas the default postgres database is always active. So it looks like my database is available but not connected. Can I choose which database to connect to? Ive been checking the docs, but can't find how to make my database active. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Describe the problems in detail, including error messages.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to PgAdmin to a Postgres instance you get to choose which database you want your queries to work against. You can see an example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/images/Postgres-Connect02.png).

If you cannot see your database once you connect to the instance you might either:
1) not have the db created in that instance.
2) not have permissions to view/access it. For this one you may need to ask to the administrator of the db for the relevant permission grants.